# How to detect Netbeans is using Java in C#?

Tags: c#, wmi

Normally when you execute Java App, you have the possibility to detect three kind of Java process :

- java.exe
- javaw.exe
- javaws.exe

With my actual C# program, i can detect these processes with WMI and find the parent process which needs Java to work. But my problem right now is a little tricky. When you have Java App executed behind a .exe. For example Minecraft, you can prove with wmi that javaw.exe is executed... but with Netbeans, There is no java process and this is really weird because this IDE is written in Java.

Anyone have an idea to prove Netbeans is using Java ? (Or maybe i'm completely wrong, it's impossible to do this in C#...)

Comment: For some Java apps that have an `.exe` in front of it, the `.exe` is just a shim.  It still depends on the JRE, etc.  [Other techniques](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html), this one provided by Netbeans itself, allow the `.exe` to be compiled entirely natively -- no external JRE.  My hunch is that this is what Netbeans is doing, though that's just a guess.

Comment: After doing some extra research, you can prove it if you inspect the process modules. You'll find some java dll.